# What do you call an application that does not come with an installer?

Tags: eclipse, unzip

what you call a software that requires no installation only unzipping like eclipse where it has no installation only we have to unzip and also for uninstalling just delete the Workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's typically called a [portable application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application).

Comment: hi Bananeweizen thanks for the reply .. but arent portable application also requires installation ..?

Comment: Typically not. You may be confused by having used one of the portable application launchers out there. Those often create "portable application packages" which still ask you for the destination drive to be installed. But that is just for convinience, you could just unzip the same program to any destination.